# CPU Over voltage error after updating BIOS

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, bios, power-supply

I have a problem with my motherboard.

I updated the BIOS on my Asus P8P67-M to the latest version(3703) after this when rebooting my computer I was shown a message telling me that there is a CPU Over voltage error and CPU temperature error. I was prompted to press F1 to enter setup and so I did. When I got into the BIOS the CPU temperature and voltage monitors were fluctuating off the charts to seemingly random values. For example it would say that one second my CPU was at 300C then -5C the next. I then thought to myself that this must be a bug. So I used the boot menu to boot into windows and once in the OS I make sure that my temperatures were all fine and to no surprise they were all normal(playing Star Wars: Battlefront, test in benchmark and prime95).

Computer boots unreliably, about 3% of the time I'll successfully boot Windows, 85%
of the time screen stays black when I turn power on, 12% of the time I get to BIOS
and get CPU Over Voltage Temperature Error. I have a spare PSU and i know its
stable and i have the same issue.

I set the CPU and RAM concerning features not to "auto" but to "value" it helped a little. Almost every time the computer starts up properly but it happens that I get a black screen and then I have to switch off and on again. Turn on the computer is also a problem because I have to use 2-3 times the power button to begin to take on.

What other options set in the BIOS?

Here are my Current settings:

[image: http://scr.hu/26ko/fjjo3]

[image: http://scr.hu/26ko/wtrez]

```
i7 2600
8 gb ramu patriot intel extreme masters
radeon 7970
asus p8p67-m
be quiet! Pure Power L8 CM 630W
```

P.S Uploading the old version BIOS did not help, upload a new chip with the BIOS also

Comment: Did anything in particular make you update the BIOS in the first place? I'd load the optimized default settings to see if that helped, but it sounds like something has gone very wrong, especially if you're getting odd sensor readings like that.

Comment: Have you tried resetting your firmware configurations to their default values?  There should be an option to do this.

Answer (score 0):

After updating the `BIOS` you need to reset it to default values because often old values don't map properly to new settings, which is why it is incorrectly reading the CPU voltage.

Choose `load bios defaults` or the equivalent in your BIOS, reboot, and then check it.  Should be fine.